# toggleSoftInput со значением ShowForced закрывает собой view

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Добился того, чтобы клавиатура при появлении сдвигала Layout, который над ней, добавив в манифест `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. Потом, мне понадобилось принудительно показать клавиатуру, что я сделал следующим образом:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(AddInboxItemActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Клавиатура дейтвительно показывается, но поверх уже существующих view, т. е. игнорируя то, что написано в манифесте. Что-нибудь можно сделать?

---

**Обновление** Код `activity` с формой ввода. Что важно, мы приходим в неё из другой активности. Если мы приходим с параметром "View", значит мы будем просматривать заметку и нам клавиатура не нужна. Если мы пришли без этого параметра, значит мы будем создавать новую заметку, где клавиатура нужна. Кроме того, кнопка "редактировать" также должна показать клавиатуру.

```
public class NotMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTitle, editNote;
    Button btnSave, btnEdit, btnCancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_inbox_item);

        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        editTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
        editNote = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.note);

        String activityMode = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mode");

        // В режиме "Просмотр заметки" нам клавиатура не нужна
        if (activityMode.equals("View")){

            // поля ввода тоже, делаем их неактивными
            editTitle.setEnabled(false);
            editNote.setEnabled(false);

            // пытаемся убрать фокус с полей, хотя они и так уже не активные, но без толку
            editTitle.clearFocus();
            editNote.clearFocus();

            btnSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnCancel.setText(R.string.back);

            // пытаемся сфокусироваться на корневом layout, но клавиатура всё рано не исчезает
           RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.layoutContainer);
           relativeLayout.requestFocus();

            // лишь этот грубый метод даёт эффект
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

            editTitle.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("title"));
            editNote.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("noteText"));
        }
        else{
            // в режиме ввода клавиатура нам нужна, она появляется при запросе фокуса
            editNote.requestFocus();
            btnEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.save_button:

                String title = editTitle.getText().toString();
                String note = editNote.getText().toString();

                DBHandler dBHandler = new DBHandler(NotMainActivity.this);
                dBHandler.addNewItem(title, note);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Сохранено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.edit_button:
                editTitle.setEnabled(true);
                editNote.setEnabled(true);
                // теперь нам нужна клавиатура, потому мы просмотрев запись, захотели её отредактировать.
                // Но из-за SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN вызов requestFocus() не сработает; клавиатура появиться только 
                //     если ткнуть пальцем в поле
                editNote.requestFocus();

                btnEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnCancel.setText(R.string.cancel);

                // Принудительно показываем клавиатуру. Она появляется, но закрывает собой кнопки "Сохранить", "Редактировать"
                // игнорируя android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" в манифесте
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(NotMainActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

                break;

            case R.id.cancel_button:
                finish();
                break;
        }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно ещё и фокус на нужное поле ввода установить

Comment: Это я уже сделал.

Comment: В теории достаточно лишь вызвать фокус. Прямо вызывать клаву может быть не обязательно. Попробуйте и то и это вызвать с задержкой в 300мс методом `postDelayed(new Runnable(){@Override run(){//тут показывайте клаву и ставьте фокус}})`

Comment: Этого не происходит, потому что я предварительно спрятал клавиатуру `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);` (тогда мне наоборот нужно было принудительно клавиатуру спрятать, и одна только установка всем полям `setEnabled(false);` не помогла)

Comment: Не стоит программно менять SOFT_INPUT_STATE по моему опыту. Лучше попробуйте через фокусы это разрулить. В теории надо изначально фокус не на EditText вызвать чтобы клавы не было. А когда она нужна - на EditText. Так и клава должна появиться и с бубном плясать не надо. Т.е. надо но в другую сторону.

Comment: Попробовал. Не помогло [такое](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117967/how-to-remove-focus-without-setting-focus-to-another-control) решение c фокусировкой на Layout, а также `edittext.clearFocus();`. Я пробовал фокусироваться не на TextEdit как до того, как они были созданы, так и после.

Comment: Попробуйте -       
    `public static void showKeyboard(Context activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
         activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }`

Comment: Вернулся к решению этой проблемы спустя почти месяц. К сожалению, это тоже не помогло. Выложил код Activity и начал конкурс.

Comment: Знаю как решить вашу проблему, сегодня вечером опубликую ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такая связка без использования флагов в манифесте работает:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE
        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. К сожалению, пока ничего не получилось, наверное потому, что я не понял, куда нужно вставлять Ваш код. Из манифеста флаг я убрал. Пробовал разными способами, но желаемого эффекта не добился. Одно понял:  при `imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);`  клавиатура закрывает собой нижнюю часть панели, вне зависимости от того, идёт `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);` до этой строки или после.

Comment: Это нужно вставить в OnClickListener. Должно заработать.

Comment: В конец блока `case: R.id.edit_button:` перед `break;`? Сделал. Результат таков: 1) При нажатии кнопки редактирования клавиатура появляется поверх интерфейса, игнорируя Ваш `setSoftInputMode`. 2) Клавиатура не появляется, когда я прихожу в активность в режиме ввода новой записи (блок `else` в методе `onCreate`) даже при вызове фокуса, а если тнкуть в неё пальцем, то появится поверх интерфейса (из манифеста флаг я же убрал).

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `editNote.requestFocus();`

Comment: После ещё порядка часа попыток сделал такой вывод: в `onClickListener` реакции на `setSoftInputMode` нет, а `toggleSoftInput` игнорирует настройку `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE`, где бы она не стояла - в манифесте или программная.

Comment: И ещё выяснил: в `onClickListener` команда `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);` вообще игнорируется, даже если вызывать клавиатуру ткнув пальцем в поле (клавиатура появится, но поверх интерфейса).

Comment: Вопрос остаётся открытым, но в благодарность за Ваше потраченное время даю Вам приз.